# Python Tkinter change Text background of some textual spans

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a very long text and I would like to highlight some spans by given offsets. 
How can I achieve that with Tkinter?

To make it more concrete, consider the following:

```
from Tkinter import *
example = """Contrary to popular belief, \n\n Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of \n\n classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
"""
offsets = [[10,20], [100,112]]

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, example)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I show the spans corresponding to `example[10:20]` and `example[100:112]` highlighted?

Comment: you can use `text.add_tag()` - http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a tag, and apply that tag to a range of characters.

You can use an index of the form `1.0 + <offset>c` which will compute a new index that is *<offset>* characters from index 1.0.

For example:

```
text.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")
for start, end in offsets:
    text.tag_add("highlight", "1.0 + %sc"%start, "1.0 + %sc"%end)
```